# How to get the value of a child node of a json array

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, android-studio

please i am having some issues parsing a list of data form the this link(https://gnews.io/api/v3/top-news?&token=dd21eb88599ccb3411eaad9b314cde23) i am able to get the data from the json array(articles) but how can i get the data from the josn array(sources)

```
    private void getWebApiData() {
        String WebDataUrl = "https://gnews.io/api/v3/top-news?&token=dd21eb88599ccb3411eaad9b314cde23";
        new AsyncHttpTask.execute(WebDataUrl);
    }

    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    public class AsyncHttpTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String result = "";

            URL url;
            HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(urls[0]);
                urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                if (result != null) {
                    String response = streamToString(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                    parseResult(response);
                    return result;
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if (result != null) {
                newsAdapter = new NewsAdapter(getActivity(), newsClassList);
                listView.setAdapter(newsAdapter);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Data Loaded Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Failed to load data!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    private String streamToString(InputStream stream) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
        String line;
        String result = "";
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            result += line;
        }

        // Close stream
        if (null != stream) {
            stream.close();
        }
        return result;
    }


    private void parseResult(String result) {
        try {
            JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONObject response2 = response.getJSONObject("articles");
            NewsClass newsClass;
            for (int i = 0; i < newsClass.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject post = newsClass.optJSONObject(i);
                String name = post.optString("name");
                newsClass = new newsClass();
                newsClass.setNews_Name(name);
                artistClassList.add(newsClass);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This is code I am using the get the data of the articles.
To get the sources I have tried

```
    private void parseResult(String result) {
        try {
            JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONObject response2 = response.getJSONArray("articles");
            JSONObject response3 = response2.getJSONObject("sources");
            NewsClass newsClass;
            for (int i = 0; i < newsClass.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject post = newsClass.optJSONObject(i);
                String name = post.optString("name");
                newsClass = new newsClass();
                newsClass.setNews_Name(name);
                artistClassList.add(newsClass);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But I think I am not getting the code correctly

Here is the second option I have tried

```
    private void parseResult(String result) {
        try {
            JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result);

            JSONObject response = response2.getJSONObject("sources");
            NewsClass newsClass;
            for (int i = 0; i < newsClass.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject post = newsClass.optJSONObject(i);
                String name = post.optString("name");
                newsClass = new newsClass();
                newsClass.setNews_Name(name);
                artistClassList.add(newsClass);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But this only gives me empty text Fields the spaces for the data is populated but it is blank
Please any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how your code works. You have tried to get `JSONObject` as **articles** which is actually `JSONArray`. Besides this I don't find any *key* in your `json` like **sources** instead I have found **source**. To parse **source** try below way:

```
try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("articles");

    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject articleObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONObject sourceObject = articleObject.getJSONObject("source");

        String name = sourceObject.optString("name");
        String url = sourceObject.optString("url");
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million really appreciate it worked just as expected

Comment: Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59816944/7926186 similar to this question and i haven't been able to get a correct answer

Comment: @Serenity, Check my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59836346/2637449

Comment: please check this: stackoverflow.com/q/59850922/7926186 i have posted another question with the full code because the application is returning empty data after trying your code i can't say if the code is wrong somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

As Md. Asaduzzaman stated it is actually an JSON array ("articles" to be exact).

I have tested it on my phone and it works no prob. You will have to try and figure out how u want the JSONArray to be parsed thou.

```
private class AsyncTaskExample extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            stringURL = new URL(strings[0]);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) stringURL.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.connect();
            is = conn.getInputStream();

            //render string stream
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line;
            String result = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                result += line;
            }

            // Close stream
            if (null != is) {
                is.close();
            }

            return result;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return str;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String js) {
        super.onPostExecute(js);
        try {
            JSONObject  jay = new JSONObject (js);
            JSONObject source = jay.getJSONObject("articles");

            String s = source.getString("title");
            System.out.println(s);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Here you will find all you need for [JSON](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/json.html).

Best of luck to you :)

Comment: Thanks alot really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
            JSONArray articles = jsonObject.getJSONArray("articles");
            for(int i=0; i<articles.length(); i++){
                JSONObject obj1 = (JSONObject) articles.get(i);
                JSONObject source = obj1.getJSONObject("source");
                Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: " + source.toString()); }
```

Hope that help you !