# how to get the values of a child array in json array

Tags: java, arrays, json, android-studio, listview

[image: My Result and Expected Result]How can i get the values of array of a child array in JSON that is the value of the A arrays 
I want to populate the result to a list such as  "Brimstone",  "Cross",  "Calvary",  This question is actually an extension of a question i have ask before the full code can be found in my previous question here [How to get the value of a child node of a json array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59738142/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-child-node-of-a-json-array)

My JSON File

```
{
  "schools": [
    {
      "A": [
        {
          "name": "Brimstone"
        },
        {
          "name": "Cross"
        },
        {
          "name": "Calvary"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My Java Code

```
    private void parseResult_GetWebData(String result) {
        try {
            JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("schools");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.optJSONObject(i);
                JSONArray jsonArray1 = jsonObject.getJSONArray("A");

                for (int k = 0; k < jsonArray1.length(); k++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray1.optJSONObject(k);
                    String name = jsonObject1.optString("name");

                    List<SchoolClass> schoolClassList;
                    schoolClassList = new ArrayList<>();

                    SchoolClass schoolClass = new SchoolClass();
                    schoolClass.setName(name);
                    schoolClassList.add(schoolClass);
                }

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

With my code i am getting blank result in my list

Comment: You have made `schoolClassList` a local variable. It is not passed anywhere. How are you claiming to populate a ListView?

Comment: @user7 i am populating the list in another activity the list is populated successfully when my JSON is written like this `{
  "A":[
        {"name" : "Brimstone"},
        {"name" : "Cross"},
        {"name" : "Calvary"}
      
  ]
}` but i need to add another array to it that is the main issue so the listView is been populated in other instance of the code but my final JSON file is written as in the question so i just the correct way to read data from schools then to A then to the values of A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this code**

**You are creating custom object array list on every object of A**

```
private void parseResult_GetWebData(String result) {
    try {
        JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("schools");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.optJSONObject(i);
            JSONArray jsonArray1 = jsonObject.getJSONArray("A");

            List<SchoolClass> schoolClassList = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int k = 0; k < jsonArray1.length(); k++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray1.optJSONObject(k);
                String name = jsonObject1.optString("name");

                SchoolClass schoolClass = new SchoolClass();
                schoolClass.setName(name);
                schoolClassList.add(schoolClass);
            }

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a simple way to solve this problem using Jackson (`ObjectMapper`)

> 1- Read JSON file
>
> 2- Deserialized it using `ObjectMapper` to `Map`
>
> 3- Access to the desired value using `Map` and `List` methods

```
 //Create objectMapper instance
 ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

 //Deserizalize
 Map map = objectMapper.readValue(jsonValue, Map.class);

 //Get desired value(List of children nodes)
 List<Map> childs = ((List<Map>)((Map)((List)objectMapper.
 readValue(file, Map.class).
 get("schools")).
 get(0)).get("A"));

 childs.stream().forEach(child->{

        System.out.println(child.get("name"));

 });
```

Results

Brimstone, Cross, Calvary

---

**Last but not least**, there is **another way** that is pretty much more standard.

> 1- Create Dtos (Java objects) according to your JSON
>
> 2- Convert JSON into Dto objects and simply use setter and getter of
>   those objects.

- **Create Dto Object for A**

  ```
  @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
  @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
  public class ADto {

  @JsonProperty(value = "name")
  private String name;

  //Getters and Setters

  }
  ```
- **Create Dto Object for Schools**

  ```
  @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
  @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
  public class SchoolDto {

  @JsonProperty(value = "A")
  private List<ADto> aDtos;

  //Getters and Setters

  }
  ```
- **Create Dto Object for Parent of JSON**

  ```
  @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
  @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
  public class ParentDto {

  @JsonProperty(value = "schools")
  List<SchoolDto> schools;

  //Getters and Setters

  }
  ```
- **Convert JSON into Dtos**

  ```
  //Create objectMapper instance
  ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

  //Deserizalize JSON
  ParentDto parentDto =objectMapper.readValue(jsonValue,ParentDto.class);

  //Get desired value
  SchoolDto schoolDto = parentDto.getSchools().get(0);
  List<ADto> names =schoolDto.getaDtos();

  //Result
  names.stream().forEach(aDto -> {
      System.out.println(aDto.getName());
  });
  ```

Comment: firstly am using a url not a file, secondly how to i get a string from this because the code seems incomplete if i stop at get("A"));

Comment: Instead of file you can put string of JSON that could recived via webservice or whatever

Comment: I'll  fix it now

Comment: @Serenit I edited it and added new snippet that shows how to get names of child nodes

Comment: @Serenity The first solution is edited and also the new solution is placed